# Exporting function inputs in parallel processing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to write a function which has a parallel computation option.
To make it work in both windows, and mac or Linux environments, I am using a PSOCK system, which I believe is a default configuration in `makeCluster()`. My question is whether I should, or it is more desirable, to pass **all** arguments to the clusters using a `clusterExport` function. If I do this, I think I need to evaluate all input arguments-- instead of the default lazy evaluation. If some variables are used only in some special cases, this does not seem desirable.

For example, in the following code, I am wondering whether I should add
`clusterExport(varlist = c("a","b","c"),cl = cl,envir = environment())` in the function. The following code works fine in my computer, but a similar code failed in other's computer.

I would be very interested to hear about the best practice as well. Thank you!

```
library(pbapply)
foo = function(a=3, b=4, c=5, B = 8, parallel = FALSE){

  if(parallel) {cl = makeCluster(4) } else{cl = NULL}


  # default a,b,c values are desired to be used 
  if(a>5){
    # c is used only in this case 
    v= pbsapply(1:B,FUN = function(i) {Sys.sleep(.5); a+b+c+i},cl = cl) 
  }else{
    v= pbsapply(1:B,FUN = function(i) {Sys.sleep(.5); a+b+i},cl = cl) 
  }

  if(parallel) stopCluster(cl)

  return(v)
}

system.time(foo())
system.time(foo(parallel = T))
```

Comment: What does "code failed in other's computer" mean? Any error message?

Comment: The error message basically said that it could not find 'a' , so I think the variables were not reported.

Comment: (disclaimer; I'm the author).  If you use the future.apply package, you don't have to worry about exporting variables; it'll be done automatically for you.  So, use `v <- future_lapply(1:B, FUN = function(i) { a+b+c+i })` will just work.  Set `plan(multisession, workers = 4L)` to run it in parallel on your local computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set defaults to `NULL` and do a case handling using `sapply`. I'm not sure, though, if this really works, because I can't reproduce your error.

```
foo <- function(a=NULL, b=NULL, c=NULL, B=NULL, parallel=FALSE) {
  if (parallel) {
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 4)  ## safer to code this more dynamically
    ## case handling:
    sapply(c("a", "b", "c", "B"), function(x) {
      if (!is.null(get(x))) clusterExport(cl, x, environment())
    })
  } else { 
    cl <- NULL
  }
  # default a,b,c values are desired to be used 
  if (a > 5) {
    # c is used only in this case 
    v <- pbsapply(1:B, FUN=function(i) {
      Sys.sleep(.2)
      a + b + c + i
    }, cl=cl) 
  } else {
    v <- pbsapply(1:B, FUN=function(i) {
      Sys.sleep(.2)
      a + b + i
    }, cl=cl) 
  }
  if (parallel) stopCluster(cl)
  return(v)
}

foo(a=3, b=4, c=5, B=8, parallel=TRUE)
#   |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed=00s  
# [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```